# Prefix for CSS3 isn't required?

Tags: css, browser, prefix

I was busy with my website using latest Chrome.

For no reason, I just started searching through code using `Inspect Element`.

I scrolled down, after I saw some rare happening. `-moz-` `-o-` `-ms-` `-webkit-` were all crossed, except `box-shadow` itself. Same happening was for every single CSS3 element, such as gradient, text-shadow, transition, box-shadow.

I was wondering if it's only for Chrome. I put the parts of code where there is prefix, between `/*` and `*/`. Then started named below browsers, using `127.0.0.1`, and it all gives me result I wanted, without any prefixes.

> Google Chrome 28.0.1500.95 `-webkit-`
>
> Internet Explorer 10.0.9200 `-ms-`
>
> Mozilla Firefox 23.0 `-moz-`
>
> Opera 15.0.1147.153 `-o-`

Why everyone kept telling me, that I **need** to do it? When all browsers support it? (I mean that, all these 4 prefixes catch all browsers).

Comment: Chrome doesn't use webkit anymore (starting with v28)

Comment: That means I should start reading documentation of each download, since I didn't knew that.

Comment: No worries, I just re-read and my comment doesn't really help answer your question much! I think the answer should help - use the prefixes if you'd like to support older versions of chrome etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to caniuse.com (first google result) the vendor prefix will support a few outdated versions of Mozilla and Webkit-based browsers.

Link: http://caniuse.com/css-boxshadow

Comment: And which query to be specific?

Comment: "box-shadow browser support"

Answer (score 1):

The current versions of Chrome/Opera use a rendering engine that has deprecated vendor prefixes. So technically you don't need to use them at least for those anymore. However, since tons of people still use old versions, as well as other webkit browsers, it's best to still include them :)

Comment: Ok, but yet? Why did browsers required a prefix, couldn't they just hang on same CSS3 rule, the content is still same.

Comment: They're used because the software vendors producing the browsers wanted to implement the new functionality pre-release of the CSS spec. Using vendor prefixes insures there aren't any changes to the functionality of the page later on down the road.